# How can nested nested records be populated in Avro using a GenericRecord

Tags: java, avro

Suppose I’ve got the following schema:

```json
{
 "name" : "Profile",
 "type" : "record",
 "fields" : [
  { "name" : "firstName", "type" : "string" },
  { 
   "name" : "address",
   "type" : {
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "AddressUSRecord",
    "fields" : [
     { "name" : "address1" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "address2" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "city" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "state" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "zip" , "type" : "int" },
     { "name" : "zip4", "type": "int" }
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I’m using a `GenericRecord` to represent each Profile that gets created.  To add a `firstName`, it’s easy to do the following:

```java
Schema  sch =  Schema.parse(schemaFile);
DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> fw = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>()).create(sch, new File(outFile));
GenericRecord r = new GenericData.Record(sch);
r.put(“firstName”, “John”);
fw.append(r);
```

But how would I set the `city`, for example?  How do I represent the key as a string that the `r.put` method can understand?

Answer (score 24):

For the schema above:

```
GenericRecord t = new GenericData.Record(sch.getField("address").schema());
t.put("city","beijing");
r.put("address",t);
```