# populating nested records in avro

Tags: java, scala, avro

new to Avro and I have the below schema id.avsc.  I am using scala to try and populate the records, my understanding is that this is a union in avro, but I don't know how to populate the individual records within the union.  Any advice in scala or java welcome:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "mytest",
  "namespace" : "risk",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "myid",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "myid1",
        "type" : "string"
      }, {
        "name" : "multiids",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "map",
          "values" : "string"
        }
      } ]
    }, {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "yourid",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "yourid2",
        "type" : "string"
      }, {
        "name" : "multiids",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "map",
          "values" : "string"
        }
      } ]
    }, {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "extraid",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "name",
        "type" : "string"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Below code gives a null pointer, guessing because these are records but not fields (but can't see a getRecord method), if I try entry at "id" field I get an error saying its "Not a record schema".  How can I do this, or something similar to populate the values in this nested union on records?

*I have tried several of the scala libs for avro, but they all have something missing, there is no one complete solution which will help with my schema.

```
import java.io.File

import org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser
import org.apache.avro.file.{DataFileReader, DataFileWriter}
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericData, GenericDatumReader, GenericDatumWriter, GenericRecord}


object Avro extends App  {
  val idSchema = scala.io.Source.fromFile("id.avsc").mkString
  val avroIdSchema = new Parser().parse(idSchema)
  val idMessage = new GenericData.Record(avroIdSchema)

  val idGenericRecord = new GenericData.Record(avroIdSchema.getField("myid").schema())
  idGenericRecord.put("myid1", "1234")
  val multiIdsMap = new java.util.HashMap[String,String]
  multiIdsMap.put("123" , "1234")
  idGenericRecord.put("multiids",multiIdsMap)
  idMessage .put("myid", idGenericRecord)
  //similar implemention for the other records, but it fails on the first one
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Scala and Avro you might consider some library (I had success with [avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s)) for handling the boilerplate for you. I guess your code would be equal to something like:

```
case class MyId(myid1: String, multiids: Map[String,String])
case class YourId(yourid2: String, multiids: Map[String, String])
case class ExtraId(name: String)
case class MyTest(myid: MyIds, yourid: YourId, extraid: ExtraId)

val record = MyTest(
  MyId("test", Map("test1" -> "test2")),
  ...
)

val format = RecordFormat[MyTest]
// record is of type GenericRecord
val genericRecord = format.to(record)
```

EDIT: Sorry I haven't noticed that you already tested some libraries... [Here is some simple example of nested record population in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480043/question-populating-nested-records-in-avro-using-a-genericrecord).

Comment: yeah avro4s was a nice library, but unfortunately it stopped 2.10 scala cross build some versions back so a lot of the newer functionality I would be needing would be missing as I'm limited to using 2.10.  I had a look at that example you had given originally and that was what I was using to develop this solution, but as you can see I can't get it working

Comment: What exactly gives you NPE? Maybe there is a problem with schema, or extracting fields from it?

Comment: This bit here : avroIdSchema.getField("myid").schema() probably because myid is a record and not a field.  However now if I try any of the field names I get the error "org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Bad index"

Comment: Try `avroIdSchema.getField("id").schema()`

Comment: If I do that, I get org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a record schema: [{"type":"record","name":"myid","namespace":"risk","fields":[{"name"